# Does Route Component in React reload the component if we visit the same path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-applications, react-router, react-router-v4

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
  <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup}></Route>
  <Route exact path="/signin" component={Signin}></Route>
  <Route exact path="/user/:userID" component={Profile}></Route>  <===(Example)
  <Route exact path="/allusers" component={Users}></Route>
</Switch>
```

What happens if my application hits the same path, will it remount the component or nothing will happen. For e.g. what happens if my application hits the route containing `/user/:userID` (I have marked the route in the code above). Will it remount the profile component or nothing will happen since the user is already on that component?

I have done some testing and it looks like if we hit the same route then nothing happens. Not sure what should be happening in such a case like what is the default behavior of Route component in such a case. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some further investigation and find out that if we hit the same route again, then the component definitely remounts but there is a difference between the first remount and the repeated remounts.

In the first remount, once the render() method of that component was called after that another lifecycle method (which was there in my component) namely **ComponentDidMount** was called which is the default lifecycle behavior. But in the further repeated remount, only the render() method was called and **ComponentDidMount** lifecycle method despite being present in the component wasn't called. I believe this happened because the component was already mounted. I'm not entirely sure about the rationale behind this event so please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks!